# Horizontal range... inside (vertical) ARRAYFORMULA?

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I need to get this formula: `COUNTA(D1:K1)` to work into an ARRAYFORMULA...

Of course by syntax, it could not be `ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTA(D1:D:K1:K))`, but `ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTA(D:K))` (obviously) counts the whole columns range, while `ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTA(D1:K1))` not work in array!

Please! I'm stucked with this  =(

Comment: Can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on, clearly indicating the desired outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
={"IMAGES TO GET"; ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="";"";countif(if(D2:K<>""; row(D2:K)); row(D2:K))-2))}
```

This seems to create the same output as the values you in column M.

For the list (column N) you can try in cell N1

```
={"List"; ArrayFormula(if(len(A2:A); regexextract(transpose(query(transpose(D2:K);;5000)); rept(".*?\s"; L2:L));))}
```

Hope that helps?

#### Reference:

- [COUNTIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480?hl=en)
- [ROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093316?hl=en)

Comment: It works perfect!! Thanks for your help! =)

Comment: Sorry @JPV!! But I saw the "numbers" in the column, ASSUMED it was working fine... and continued with another part of my work. Today I return to this and (wanting to use those values) and discover that in fact, the formula is returning the count of cells that contain a value... but FROM THE PREVIOUS ROW !? That is, in row 2, I am actually getting the value that corresponds to row 1... To clarify: row 1 (range D1-K1) contains the "header" of the column (the title), so the result of the formula in row 2, returns an "8" since the range D1: K1 is obviously "complete" Any way to fix that??

Comment: The formula has to be used in row 1. Did you do that? If you need further help, would it be possible to share a copy of your spreadsheet (sensitive data erased)?

Comment: Hi, JPV! Thanks for your kindly help!! Since I cannot publicly share the content of my sheet, I made a sample with the same data type ... I hope it helps you to give me a hand with this, even because I have a similar problem with OFFSET, in another column! (does not support ARRAYFORMULA!)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18IRl87PWvnII4iZ-cuCYa4iwSrw8Pqia2KJSqEJ9v8E/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Speedbit: thanks for the sample. Change the formula in L1 to ={"IMAGES TO GET"; ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="";"";countif(if(D2:K<>""; row(D2:K)); row(D2:K))-2))} and updated my answer. See if that helps?

Comment: what can I say?? You're the man! jejeje THANK YOU VERY VERY MUCH!  =D

Comment: in addition... is possible to get the LIST, but comma separated as I intended in column O?

Comment: Yes, substitue spaces (" ") with comma (", "). Something like this should work: ={"IMG LIST"; ArrayFormula(if(len(A2:A); substitute(trim(regexextract(transpose(query(transpose(D2:K);;5000)); rept(".*?\s"; L2:L)));" "; ", ");))}

Comment: I've already did it by REGEXREPLACE/TRIM and get the expected!!... just in case my solution, was not a "good practice"! THANKS A LOT!! You are the best, man! =D